# Display custom field values of product variations to custom product tab in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I successfully created a 3 custom field for each product variation and it's properly working (saving, updating).

*For this I use the following code:*

```php
/* Add custom field input @ Product Data > Variations > Single Variation */
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'add_custom_field_cage_code_to_variations', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_field_cage_code_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    echo '<div class="cage_code_options_group options_group">';
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => 'cage_code[' . $loop . ']',
            'class' => 'short',
            'label' => __( 'Cage Code', 'magazine' ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-field form-row form-row-first',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code', true )
        ));

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => 'cage_code_part_number[' . $loop . ']',
            'class' => 'short',
            'label' => __( 'Cage Code - Part #', 'magazine' ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-field form-row form-row-last',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code_part_number', true )
        ));

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number[' . $loop . ']',
            'class' => 'short',
            'label' => __( 'NIIN/NSN Number', 'magazine' ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-field form-row form-row-first',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number', true )
        ));
    echo '</div>';
}

/* Save custom field on product variation save */
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'magazine_save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
function magazine_save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $cage_code = $_POST['cage_code'][$i];
    if ( isset( $cage_code ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'cage_code', esc_attr( $cage_code ) );

    $cage_code_part_number = $_POST['cage_code_part_number'][$i];
    if ( isset( $cage_code ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'cage_code_part_number', esc_attr( $cage_code_part_number ) );

    $cage_code_niin_nsn_number = $_POST['cage_code_niin_nsn_number'][$i];
    if ( isset( $cage_code_niin_nsn_number ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number', esc_attr( $cage_code_niin_nsn_number ) );
}
```

[image]

---

*Then I created a new product tab:*

```php
// Add a custom product data tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_cage_code_info_tab' );
function woo_cage_code_info_tab( $tabs ) {
    
    // Adds the new tab 
    $tabs['cage_code_information_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Cage Code Information', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_cage_code_info_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}

function woo_cage_code_info_tab_content() {
?>
    <script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
        <div class="woocommerce-variation-cage-code">
        {{{ data.variation.cage_code}}}
        </div>
    </script>

<?php
}
```

[image]

---

### **My problem**

The custom fields are not displaying on the new product tab I created. I tried to use this code. As applied in next  [tutorial](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-field-product-variation/) and put it inside the product tab.

```php
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-cage-code">
        {{{ data.variation.custom_field}}}
    </div>
</script>
```

But the data is displaying in the variable section (above add to cart button).

---

### **My question**

Is there a way to display the custom fields inside the new product tab that will change the value when select dropdown variable is changed like the data on 'Additional Information' Tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your callback function you could use the following

- The display/output is updated accordingly with the dropdown select menu for variable products

```php
function woo_cage_code_info_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        // Loop through the variation IDs
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $key => $variation_id ) {
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation Object
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
            
            // Get meta
            $cage_code = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code' );
            $cage_code_part_number = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code_part_number' );
            $cage_code_niin_nsn_number = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number' );
            
            // Output
            echo '<div class="woo_cage_code_info_tab_content woo_cage_code_info_tab_content-' . $variation_id .'">';
            
            if ( $cage_code ) {
                echo '<p>Cage code: ' . $cage_code . '</p>';
            }

            if ( $cage_code_part_number ) {
                echo '<p>Cage code part number: ' . $cage_code_part_number . '</p>';
            }
            
            if ( $cage_code_niin_nsn_number ) {
                echo '<p>Cage code niin nsn_number: ' . $cage_code_niin_nsn_number . '</p>';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Hide all
            $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

            // Change
            $( 'input.variation_id' ).change( function() {
                // Hide all
                $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                if( $( 'input.variation_id' ).val() != '' ) {
                    var var_id = $( 'input.variation_id' ).val();

                    // Display current
                    $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content-' + var_id ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```