# Print styled HTML as custom field output from admin meta box fields in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have this code, based on [Display custom field values of product variations to custom product tab in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63011510/11987538) to display 3 custom field on WooCommerce variations.

In that fields I want to insert text with HTML tags and show it in shortcode with all HTML styling (tables etc...) but current code doesn't output styled text but raw text with printed HTML tags:

`<div>some text etc...</div><a>some link</a>`

Any suggestions what I did wrong here?

```php
/* Add custom field input @ Product Data > Variations > Single Variation */
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'add_custom_field_cage_code_to_variations', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_field_cage_code_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    echo '<div class="cage_code_options_group options_group">';
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => 'cage_code[' . $loop . ']',
            'label' => __( 'One-line description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code', true )
        ));

        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
            'id' => 'cage_code_part_number[' . $loop . ']',
            'label' => __( 'Short Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code_part_number', true )
        ));

        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
            'id' => 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number[' . $loop . ']',
            'label' => __( 'Long description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number', true )
        ));
    echo '</div>';
}

/* Save custom field on product variation save */
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'magazine_save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
function magazine_save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $cage_code = $_POST['cage_code'][$i];
    if ( isset( $cage_code ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'cage_code', esc_attr( 
    $cage_code ) );

    $cage_code_part_number = $_POST['cage_code_part_number'][$i];
    if ( isset( $cage_code ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'cage_code_part_number', 
    esc_attr( $cage_code_part_number ) );

    $cage_code_niin_nsn_number = $_POST['cage_code_niin_nsn_number'][$i];
    if ( isset( $cage_code_niin_nsn_number ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 
    'cage_code_niin_nsn_number', esc_attr( $cage_code_niin_nsn_number ) );
}

function woo_cage_code_info_tab_content() {
     global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        // Loop through the variation IDs
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $key => $variation_id ) {
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation Object
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
            
            // Get meta
            $cage_code = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code' );
            $cage_code_part_number = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code_part_number' );
            $cage_code_niin_nsn_number = $variation->get_meta( 
     'cage_code_niin_nsn_number' );
            
            // Output
            echo '<div class="woo_cage_code_info_tab_content 
     woo_cage_code_info_tab_content-' . $variation_id .'">';
            
            if ( $cage_code ) {
                echo '<p>' . $cage_code . '</p>';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Hide all
            $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

            // Change
            $( 'input.variation_id' ).change( function() {
                // Hide all
                $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                if( $( 'input.variation_id' ).val() != '' ) {
                    var var_id = $( 'input.variation_id' ).val();

                    // Display current
                    $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content-' + var_id ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_shortcode('woo_cage_code_info_tab_content', 'woo_cage_code_info_tab_content');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains some minor mistakes. You can use `woocommerce_wp_text_input()` or `woocommerce_wp_textarea_input()` without issues.

However, do not use `esc_attr()` when saving because it's for escaping HTML attributes (I assume that you as admin only have access to the backend fields) **OR** if you do use it, convert HTML entities back to characters at the output. In this answer I have used `wp_kses_post()` and `wp_unslash()`

The `woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object` replaces the outdated `woocommerce_save_product_variation` hook

So you get:

```php
// Add field(s)
function action_woocommerce_variation_options( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    echo '<div class="cage_code_options_group options_group">';

        woocommerce_wp_text_input(
            array(
                'id'    => 'cage_code[' . $loop . ']',
                'label' => __( 'One-line description', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code', true )
            )
        );

        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
            array(
                'id'    => 'cage_code_part_number[' . $loop . ']',
                'label' => __( 'Short Description', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code_part_number', true )
            )
        );

        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
            array(
                'id'    => 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number[' . $loop . ']',
                'label' => __( 'Long description', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number', true )
            )
        );

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'action_woocommerce_variation_options', 10, 3 );

// Save
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object( $variation, $i ) {
    // Isset
    if ( isset( $_POST['cage_code'][$i] ) ) {
        // Store
        $cage_code = wp_kses_post( wp_unslash( $_POST['cage_code'][$i] ) );

        // Update
        $variation->update_meta_data( 'cage_code', $cage_code );
    }

    // Isset
    if ( isset( $_POST['cage_code_part_number'][$i] ) ) {
        // Store
        $cage_code_part_number = wp_kses_post( wp_unslash( $_POST['cage_code_part_number'][$i] ) );

        // Update
        $variation->update_meta_data( 'cage_code_part_number', $cage_code_part_number );
    }

    // Isset
    if ( isset( $_POST['cage_code_niin_nsn_number'][$i] ) ) {
        // Store
        $cage_code_niin_nsn_number = wp_kses_post( wp_unslash( $_POST['cage_code_niin_nsn_number'][$i] ) );

        // Update
        $variation->update_meta_data( 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number', $cage_code_niin_nsn_number );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 10, 2 );
```

Then I have no idea why you would use a shortcode versus a hook to render, like I did this in my answer. This can be any hook as long as it applies to the single product page:

```php
// Display
function filter_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Adds the new tab 
    $tabs['cage_code_information_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Cage Code Information', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_cage_code_info_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'filter_woocommerce_product_tabs', 100, 1 );

function woo_cage_code_info_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        // Loop through the variation IDs
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $key => $variation_id ) {
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation Object
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
            
            // Get meta
            $cage_code = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code' );
            $cage_code_part_number = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code_part_number' );
            $cage_code_niin_nsn_number = $variation->get_meta( 'cage_code_niin_nsn_number' );
            
            // Output
            echo '<div class="woo_cage_code_info_tab_content woo_cage_code_info_tab_content-' . $variation_id .'">';
            
            if ( $cage_code ) {
                echo '<p>Cage code: ' . $cage_code . '</p>';
            }

            if ( $cage_code_part_number ) {
                echo '<p>Cage code part number: ' . $cage_code_part_number . '</p>';
            }
            
            if ( $cage_code_niin_nsn_number ) {
                echo '<p>Cage code niin nsn_number: ' . $cage_code_niin_nsn_number . '</p>';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Hide all
            $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

            // Change
            $( 'input.variation_id' ).change( function() {
                // Hide all
                $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                if( $( 'input.variation_id' ).val() != '' ) {
                    var var_id = $( 'input.variation_id' ).val();

                    // Display current
                    $( '.woo_cage_code_info_tab_content-' + var_id ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```